# With Three.js, why is the webgl canvas's height and width double the css style height and width for the same element?

Tags: three.js

I noticed while working with three.js that the webgl canvas element's height and width is getting set to double the css style height and width that's set in the window resize function. Wondering why this is because I'm running into some bugs while using some custom build shaders with Effects Composer.

[image: Showing the double height width for the webgl canvas]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably has to do with the device-pixel-ratio, which i think is 2 on retina-screens. Here is the code that sets the values for the canvas-element: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L353-L379

The default-value for the pixel-ratio is 1, and it should probably stay that way if you are doing pixel-shader heavy operations in full-screen. Search through your code for `setPixelRatio()` and remove it.

Comment: You're correct, not sure how I never noticed that in effect before!